# Select menu are not working/opening on a single tap event in the ipad in jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I have created a jquery mobile application in jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js version where there are three select menus on a page each opens in new window using `data-native-menu="false"` and

```js
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
});
```

Here is the code I am using to create the Select menu :

```asp
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="white-space: normal;">
   @Html.DropDownList("a", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["b"], "c",new  Dictionary<string, object>{{"id", "a"},{"data-shadow","false"},{"data-iconshadow","false"},{"data-native-menu","false"},{"data-theme","a"}})
</div>
```

This drop down menu responds after two-three taps on it on ipad.

Please suggest possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the CSS of the element to

```
style="cursor:pointer"
```

in order to fully catch the click/tap events on iPad.